# how to provide the password automatically in lua script while sshing on the remote machine

Tags: linux, lua

Without using sshpass, sshkeys is there any way to do ssh to a remote machine and provide the password through the lua script only.And also to run a shell command in the background on remote machine after sshing. 
How should i take password automatically after executing os.execute('ssh user@192.168.14.81')

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions. Instead show the script you are working on and state where the problem is. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Comment: why this command is terminating the process :os.execute('sshpass  -p  lee123 ssh user@192.168.14.81 "nohup sudo tcpdump -i wlan0 -w t5.pcap &"')

Comment: Either because `&` does detach the `nohup` from terminal and `ssh` command then considers its job done. Or because somewhere along the line there's error with terminals not being allocated or some such.

Comment: is there any solution to run the process in the background.

Comment: i tried this also but did'nt work:os.execute('sshpass -p lee123 ssh user@192.168.14.81 "nohup sudo tcpdump -i wlan0 -w t5.pcap &> /dev/null &"')

Answer (score 0):

That function is not supposed to be used like that. `os.execute` and `io.popen` are not really meant to be used at all, actually. They're barebones commands for when you need to do things that are not supposed to work this way but you really need to.

They're both based on standard C library and don't have much to offer. And ssh is handling its interaction with users in some not-so-standard way for security reasons. In general you'll have to use non-standard libraries, like luaposix, or attach some C++ libs for system interaction.

In relation to ssh, there is python library `parallel-ssh`. Older versions did their thing through ugly parsing of outputs, newer seem to reimplement the whole protocol. With enough desire, it'd be possible to make use of those with lua. Or just use python for the task.

Ass for peculiarities of lua interaction with processes, you may try this code (put it in a file as it'll clog stdin if you try pasting it in terminal)

```
f=io.popen([[
    echo "this will show only on f:read";
    echo "now here's your line"; 
    read var; echo $var
]]); 
print('this will print before bash command finishes, now type something'); 
f:write('This will be ignored completely')
print(f:read('*a')); 
print('This will print after the bash command');  
f:close()
```